Законодательствами или законодательством государств
Скажите, пожалуйста, в таком предложении как правильно будет писать:

Определяют возможность подписания акта в соотвествии с
законодательствами стран - участниц Совета.

Или:

Определяют возможность подписания акта в соотвествии с
законодательством стран - участниц Совета.


Скорее ед. число, сравнить: В рамках государств – членов конфедерации действуют свои установленные местным законодательством бюджетные и налоговые системы.

Правильно:
Определяют возможность подписания акта в соответствии с законодательством стран — участниц Совета.
Пояснение
При подписании акта учитывается свод законов каждой страны в отдельности.
Большой толковый словарь русского языка
ЗАКОНОДАТЕЛЬСТВО, -а; ср. 1. Совокупность, свод законов (1 
зн.) какой-л. страны или какой-л. области права. Трудовое з. 
Уголовное з.


Может вам переформулировать предложение?
Например: "Каждая из стран (участниц Совета) определяет возможность подписания акта в соответствии со своим законодательством."
